# Unable to add multiple documents/records to mlab at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mlab

I am working on building a basic CRUD API with Node.js MongoDB and Express.js. The connection to the database is successful and I am able to make GET/POST/PUT calls. I have been adding one record at a time through POSTMAN and mLab, for which an id gets generated. When I try to add multiple records at once, these records get pushed under a single id. I am unable to add multiple records at once such that each record gets a separate id.

Alternatively, is there any way I can connect this app to a database present in MongoDB Compass?

**config.js**

```js
// url: Our MongodB connection url.
//serverport: Our listening server port.


module.exports = {
    url: 'mongodb://user:password@ds253408.mlab.com:53408/productsappdb',
    serverport: 3000 
}
```

**product.controller.js**

```js
const Product = require('./product.model.js');

//Create new Product
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Request validation
    if(!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Product content can not be empty"
        });
    }

    // Create a Product
    const product = new Product({
        title: req.body.title || "No product title", 
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
        company: req.body.company
    });

    // Save Product in the database
    product.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Something wrong while creating the product."
        });
    });
};

// Retrieve all products from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Product.find()
    .then(products => {
        res.send(products);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Something wrong while retrieving products."
        });
    });
};

// Find a single product with a productId
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    Product.findById(req.params.productId)
    .then(product => {
        if(!product) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });            
        }
        res.send(product);
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Something wrong retrieving product with id " + req.params.productId
        });
    });
};

// Update a product
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    // Validate Request
    if(!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Product content can not be empty"
        });
    }

    // Find and update product with the request body
    Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.productId, {
        title: req.body.title || "No product title", 
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
        company: req.body.company
    }, {new: true})
    .then(product => {
        if(!product) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });
        }
        res.send(product);
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Something wrong updating note with id " + req.params.productId
        });
    });
};

// Delete a note with the specified noteId in the request
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
    Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.productId)
    .then(product => {
        if(!product) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });
        }
        res.send({message: "Product deleted successfully!"});
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId' || err.name === 'NotFound') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Could not delete product with id " + req.params.productId
        });
    });
};
```

**product.model.js**

```js
//create a product model in our app folder in order to save the data in our db

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    company: String
}, {
    //This property will add two fields automatically to schema. 
    //These fields are : createdAt and updatedAt in your schema.
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', ProductSchema);
```

**products.routes.js**

```js
module.exports = (app) => {
    const products = require('./product.controller.js');

    // Create a new Product
    app.post('/products', products.create);

    // Retrieve all Products
    app.get('/products', products.findAll);

    // Retrieve a single Product with productId
    app.get('/products/:productId', products.findOne);

    // Update a Note with productId
    app.put('/products/:productId', products.update);

    // Delete a Note with productId
    app.delete('/products/:productId', products.delete);
}
```

**server.js**

```js
// get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// parse requests
/*
Node.js body parser middleware. It parses 
the incoming request bodies in a 
middleware before your handlers, 
available under the req.body property.
*/

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

/*
We might face Access-Control-Allow-Origin error messages.
Hence we are enabling CORS in our server.js file to avoid the same.
*/


//Enable CORS for all HTTP methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

// Configuring the database
const config = require('./config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./product.routes.js')(app); //import route file 

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect(config.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
    process.exit();
});

// default route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to Book Product app"});
});

/*
// listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
*/

// listen on port 3000
app.listen(config.serverport, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

These are the records I am trying to insert:

```
{
"products": [{
    "title": "HP",
    "description": "15 inch laptop",
    "price": "1300",
    "company": "HP"
}, {
    "title": "Lenovo",
    "description": "14 inch laptop",
    "price": "1250",
    "company": "Lenovo"
}, {
    "title": "Dell",
    "description": "16 inch laptop",
    "price": "1450",
    "company": "Dell"
}]}
```

This is how I want my list of documents in mLab to look like(after adding multiple records at once):

[image]

Comment: What Client are you using for `models` in your code?

Comment: @AkifHussain - included code for clarity.